# SQL Server Trigger that inserts into specific user's row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

Working on a trigger that gets from the `people_hist` table the `unique ID` of the `event` and inserts back to the `people` into the column `"lastEventID"` for the user that the event was for. 
The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to add the condition into this trigger. Tried joining:

```
JOIN people p
ON i.userid=p.userid
```

But it doesn't work and I think it's quite of heresy there. I am not an `SQL` expert but we need that for the reporting purposes. I would greatly appreciate any help from you.

EDIT:
The "people" table contains all data of the users that are in the database. There is a trigger that inserts all changes of any users into the "people_hist" table. In the people_hist each event has its unique ID that I need to transfer back to the people table as "eventLastID".
e.g User with ID 456 changes his last name, trigger catches this change and inserts into people_hist as

```
ID,UserID,Old_value,New_value
1,456,X,Y
```

I need that eventID to be inserted into people that user 456 will have his lastevent value as "1".
I need that to create a report with delta of the changes for another system.
The trigger that I tried to implement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_eventid_people ON people_hist
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO people
        (EventLastID)
    SELECT
        id
        FROM inserted as i
    JOIN people as p  on i.id=p.userid

GO
```

Is there any way to make it working?

Comment: Even an SQL expert can't tell you anything without the full code of the trigger and information about your data model please provide these details

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Done, added more info.

Comment: Presuming any insert into history is for a user that already exists, you should be using UPDATE not INSERT.

Comment: @Uueerdo How could I even think about insert. You're right, now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there should be an update, not an insert.
Now it looks like this and works as I wanted:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_eventid_people ON people_hist
FOR INSERT
AS

UPDATE people
SET
      eventLastID = (SELECT inserted.id
                            FROM inserted
                            WHERE inserted.userid=people.userid)
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted
        WHERE inserted.userid=people.userid
    )
GO
```

Comment: Using a joining UPDATE, rather than two correlated subqueries, might have better performance characteristics.